# DB2 Sql order - SQL0104N

Tags: sql, db2

I have a problem with the following `SQL` code based on the database `TERRA`. The code should return all the organizations which only have European countries as members.

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.Name FROM Organisation O, ist_Mitglied iM, Land L,
umfasst U WHERE O.Abkuerzung = iM.Organisation AND iM.Land = L.L_ID
AND L.L_ID = U.land AND Kontinent LIKE 'Europa%' AND EXCEPT (SELECT
DISTINCT O.Name FROM Organisation O, ist_Mitglied iM, Land L, umfasst
U WHERE O.Abkuerzung = iM.Organisation AND iM.Land = L.L_ID AND L.L_ID
= U.land AND Kontinent NOT LIKE 'Europa%');
```

The error message is the following:

> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "DISTINCT" was found following "' AND EXCEPT 
>   (SELECT".  Expected tokens may include:  "(".  SQLSTATE=42601

Do you have any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

`EXCEPT` is a set-based operator.  It should not be preceded with `AND`.  And, `DISTINCT` is unnecessary.  Try this:

```
SELECT O.Name
FROM Organisation O JOIN
     ist_Mitglied iM
     ON O.Abkuerzung = iM.Organisation JOIN
     Land L JOIN
     ON iM.Land = L.L_ID
     umfasst U
     ON L.L_ID = U.land WHERE  Kontinent LIKE 'Europa%'
EXCEPT  
SELECT O.Name
FROM Organisation O JOIN
     ist_Mitglied iM
     ON O.Abkuerzung = iM.Organisation JOIN
     Land L JOIN
     ON iM.Land = L.L_ID
     umfasst U
     ON L.L_ID = U.land
 WHERE Kontinent NOT LIKE 'Europa%';
```

There are other ways to write the query.  This seems closest to the way you are attempting to write the query in your question.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I would not say NEVER use commas for joins. Sometimes it will solve your problem like in situations when you need recursion. There is an exception to most rules :-)

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher . . . I would and do say *NEVER use commas in the `FROM` clause*.  I give students 0 credit for a question, if their SQL has that obsolete construct.

Comment: So what will you do when you experience a SQL0345 in a recursive query?